# What meant Lord Mansfield by 'form', 'turn parties around upon frivolous objections', and 'ruin'?

Tags: england-and-wales

1. What does 'form' mean? Excessive formality, e.g. completing the wrong form or pleading the wrong cause of action?
2. I can't guess the meaning.
3. How do 1 and 2 ruin and destroy both?

[Primary Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=wW0sAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA966&lpg=PA966&dq=%22i+never+like+to+entangle+justice+in+matters+of+form%22&source=bl&ots=VPlYAL4QJh&sig=EH3MMrTullWrYp9_Ll7j-j_LOa8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN2oW0zKHWAhXH44MKHTogBI8Q6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22i%20never%20like%20to%20entangle%20justice%20in%20matters%20of%20form%22&f=false). Secondary Sources:

[*Laughing at the Gods: Great Judges and How They Made the Common Law*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107662761), p. 32 Middle.

> Although Mansfield's more expansive judicial style is 
>   hardly considered novel or original today, its innovative and 
>   almost groundbreaking quality at the time cannot be exag- 
>   gerated. Judges tended to see themselves as operating under 
>   more prosaic restrictions than the poetic Mansfield would 
>   allow. He was unafraid to irrigate the dry soil of legal rules 
>   with more invigorating waters. For instance, in *Trueman v. 
>   Fenton* in 1777, he opined that "**I never like to entangle 
>   justice in matters of 
>   [1.] form [End of 1.] and
>
>   [2.]      to turn parties around upon frivolous objections [End of 2.]
>
>   where I can avoid it —
>
>   [3.] it only tends to 
>   the ruin and destruction of both. [End of 3.]**"
>   Consequently, Mansfield 
>   believed not that he was making new law but that he was 
>   liberating the real and abiding principles of the common 
>   law from the enchainment of earlier mistaken characteri- 
>   zations. As he put it in *Pugh v. Duke of Leeds* in the same 
>   year, the proper judicial task was "not to make new law, but 
>   to vindicate the old from misrepresentation." Although he 
>   did not go so far as to declare that unjust rules could not be 
>   law (as some of his later judicial heirs, like Tom Denning, 
>   have done), he did work his hardest to make law and justice 
>   coalesce.

*Lord Mansfield: Justice in the Age of Reason*, [p. 229 Middle](https://books.google.com/books?id=7yy3BgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA229&ots=lyXh5JaMjs&dq=%22i%20never%20like%20to%20entangle%20justice%20in%20matters%20of%20form%22&pg=PA229#v=onepage&q=%22i%20never%20like%20to%20entangle%20justice%20in%20matters%20of%20form%22&f=false).

> Mansfield's decisions in commercial cases, as in other areas of the law, 
>   were intensely practical. Where he thought it necessary or appropriate, he 
>   abandoned the formality Of traditional common law pleading rules in order 
>   to provide legal protection to a broad range of commercial assets, transactions, and practices.<sup>70</sup> His aim was to get as quickly as possible to the essential issue or issues involved in a dispute and to resolve the dispute in 
>   accordance with principles Of justice and fair dealing. He Stated in one opinion: "**I never like to entangle justice in matters of form, and to turn parties 
>   round on frivolous objections where I can avoid it. It only tends to the ruin 
>   and destruction of both** ... The question therefore ... is ... whether the facts 
>   support the merits of the defendant's plea."<sup>71</sup>

Answer (score 1):

He means [this](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/%22Equity+regards+substance+rather+than+form.%22):

> **"Equity regards substance rather than form."**
>
> Equity will not permit justice to be withheld just because of a technicality. Formalities that frustrate justice will be disregarded and a better approach found for each case. Equity enforces the spirit rather than the letter of the law alone.